# Swift JSON starts with array parsing

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have an issue parsing following JSON, the problem is that it starts with an array. What should be the initial struct where I would identify the array?  if there was something like "data" before the array I would create another struct and mention data: `[Item]?` there but this JSON just starts with array.

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "TEST text"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "TEST text"
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "TEST text"
  }
]

struct Item: Codable {
    var userId: Int?
    var id: Int?
    var title: String?
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create another struct, you should simply do `JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self,from: data)`.

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't make `userId`, `id` and `title` optionals if they don't have to be.

Comment: Thanks David! I actually already tried it but Xcode was giving me an error now I tried again and it worked.

Comment: Just a small piece of advice: Swift goes to great lengths to always be sure which properties are proper references. Your programming will work out a lot easier if you manage to get rid of the optionals in your `struct` definition.

Answer (score 0):

> You have to add one more struct:

**First Way**

```
struct totalItem: Codable {
    var total: [Item]?
}
struct Item: Codable {
    var userId: Int?
    var id: Int?
    var title: String?
}
let myStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(totalItem.self, from: data)
```

**The second way to do that:**

```
let myStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data )
```